# HubL / Twig: Not finding value from array

Tags: arrays, twig, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-cms

In HubSpot, I've created a custom module called `footer`. `footer` has five field types of menu:

[image]

I've created an array where all five of the above menu ID's are pushed to an array. I've done this via a `template partial` file which is `included` in my footer module.

```
<!-- creating array -->
{% set footer_id_array = [] %}

<!-- push menu id's to array -->
{% do footer_id_array.append(module.menus.menu_column_1) %}
{% do footer_id_array.append(module.menus.menu_column_2) %}
{% do footer_id_array.append(module.menus.menu_column_3) %}
{% do footer_id_array.append(module.menus.menu_column_4) %}
{% do footer_id_array.append(module.menus.menu_column_5) %}
```

Running `{{ footer_id_array }}` shows all the IDs in the array, i.e.

```
[29420054435, 29420223163, 29420054590, 29420158158, 29420071857]
```

So this is correct, the array contains the IDs.

Now, for each item in this array, I want to generate a `nav`, so in my `footer custom module`, I have the following:

```
{% set iterations = range(0, 5) %}

{% for i in iterations %}
     <nav>
          {% menu id="{{ footer_id_array[i] }}" %}
     </nav>
{% endfor %}
```

However, on my page, this just prints HubSpots default menus, not the ones assigned to the ID's.

Why is this?

Comment: Try `{% menu id=footer_id_array[i] %}`. `{{ ... }}` is used to output stuff, but it's not renderend inside quotes inside twig tags

Comment: @DarkBee - Thanks, but I've already tried that, it didn't work, produced the same results as above (shows default menus)

Comment: Did you try using the function [menu](https://designers.hubspot.com/docs/hubl/functions#menu) rather than the tag?

Comment: @DarkBee - ah didn't know that existed. I've managed to implement it using `menu`, thanks for bringing it to my attention :)